# Style on colgroup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following colgroup not working properly.

```
<colgroup class="" style="background-color:#FF0000;"></colgroup>
```

Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kKuGg/). My styles on colgroup not working.

Comment: I found that, td has also contain a color. I to override colgroup color.

Answer (score 6):

Most properties that you can set on `colgroup` won’t have an effect, since by definitions, table cells inherit properties from `tr` elements (rows), not columns or column groups (to the extent that there is inheritance).

Set, in CSS, the properties directly on the cell elements. For example, to set the background color of the first two columns, assuming that only `td` markup is used for the cells, use

```
td:first-child, td:first-child + td {
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This means it is not possible to use colgroup style if your element has this style. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of colgroup:

```
<html> <body>

<table width="100%" border="1">   <colgroup style="background-color:#22FF22;"></colgroup>   <colgroup style="background-color:#888888;"></colgroup>   <colgroup style="background-color:#FF0000;"></colgroup>

  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>  
 </tr>  
 <tr>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td>I</td> 
 </tr>
</table>

</body> </html>
```

if your code is bit different show us the more code to repy appropriately..