# How do I get styles (besides background-color) working on colgroup?

Tags: html, css, html-table, colgroup

I can't get any style except background-color to work on a colgroup or col.  I've tried both Chrome and Firefox. I've tested this eight ways to Sunday and also googled it every way I can think of.

Is that correct, its not supported in current browsers? (on not designed to work in the spec?) or is there something I'm doing wrong?  I've tried the below style on both the colgroup and by including cols inside colgroup.

Colours silver and yellow background show up as expected, but font-family sans-serif and font-style italic do not.  What I really want to get working is the position: sticky and left: __px but I can't even get simple font styles to work yet.

For example (this is valid html5 per validator.w3.org):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Pre-table content<br />
            Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.
            Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.
            Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.
            Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.
            Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.
            Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.
        </p>
        <table>
            <colgroup span="3" style="background-color: silver; font-style: italic; width: 50px; position: sticky; left: 0px"></colgroup>
            <colgroup span="10" style="background-color: yellow; font-family: sans-serif"></colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <tr style="position: sticky; top: 0px; background-color: white; z-index: 1">
                    <th>Property Object ID</th>
                    <th>Property 1</th>
                    <th>Property 2</th>
                    <th>Property 3</th>
                    <th>Property 4</th>
                    <th>Property 5</th>
                    <th>Property 6</th>
                    <th>Property 7</th>
                    <th>Property 8</th>
                    <th>Property 9</th>
                    <th>Property 10</th>
                    <th>Property 11</th>
                    <th>Property 12</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1000001</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1000002</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1000003</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1000004</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1000005</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1000006</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1000007</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1000008</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1000009</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1000010</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1000011</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1000012</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                    <td>Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.  All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy. Onomatopoeiaonomatopoeiaonomatopoeia.</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Similar questions (but 10 and 12 y old) here [Style on colgroup not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983648/style-on-colgroup-not-working) and here [HTML table colgroup element not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658693/html-table-colgroup-element-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

The font-related properties don’t apply for columns or column groups in CSS. That’s mainly because it’s not entirely trivial to figure out to which column a given cell belongs, I believe. Especially with the fixed layout algorithm, which should only require one pass through the table.

See [Table formatting](https://www.sitepoint.com/table-formatting/?_ga=2.181555751.1031173197.1668819314-1023940438.1668819314) in the CSS reference for details about which properties apply.

You’ll need to assign this class to each individual cell (td and th) in that column group, I’m afraid.